# My Volvo XC90 will start without key in the vicinity

Tags: volvo, ignition-key, xc90

My XC90 2016 Volvo starts without the key in the vicinity. Stopped at station and spouse went off to shop. Turned off engine. pumped gas, turned on engine and picked up spouse who thought I was stuck half-mile away.

Anyone else had this happened?

Comment: I've witnessed similar in a friend's Toyota.  The engine would repeatedly randomly start, usually in his garage overnight or in supermarket car parks.  After three months of trying to fix it, the dealer just gave him a new car under the guarantee.